# Why did Chouji get fat when he received Naruto and Kurama's Chakra?

Tags: naruto

Why did Chouji get fat from receiving Naruto and Kurama's Chakra? Chouji didn't activate any technique for it to happen, actually he was surprised.

Do Akimichi bodies just naturally convert chakra into fat?

[image]

Comment: How I wish I can have a body that naturally convert fat to chakra. The reverse of the Akimichi bodies. +1 though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Naruto Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Akimichi_Clan), the Akimichi clan:

> Members of the clan possess great physical strength and are able to
>   quickly convert calories into chakra

So, they have the ability to convert calories into chakra, apparently they can do the opposite too, getting chakra and quickly convert into calories.
Maybe this one never happened to Chouji before, because he never received this amount of chackra, so he was surprised.

Comment: This might also be a result of the healing nature of Kyubi's chakra..